# jquery accordion action on open

Tags: jquery, accordion

I'm looking for a way to do something as soon as one of the tabs of an jQuery accordion has been opened and find out which tab was opened?
I've noticed there is an option 'change' which can call a function with parameters 'event' and 'ui', but can't find a way to use them to determine which tab was opened?

Comment: Are you using a jQuery plugin? If so, which one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#events) of jQuery UI accordion clearly shows how to implement the change event:

```
$('.ui-accordion').bind('accordionchange', function(event, ui) {
    ui.newHeader // jQuery object, activated header
    ui.oldHeader // jQuery object, previous header
    ui.newContent // jQuery object, activated content
    ui.oldContent // jQuery object, previous content
});
```

The `ui.newHeader` property refers to the `<h3>` element which is being opened. `ui.newContent` points to the `<div>` containing the accordion's content.

The `oldHeader` and `oldContent` properties point to the `<h3>` and `<div>` elements of the closing accordion section.

All of these properties are jQuery objects, so `ui.newContent` is similar to `$(".ui-accordion-content:visible");`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm trying to find a way to get the id or something from this div; I've tried something like ui.newcontent.id but that seems to be undifined?

Comment: @user485659 As I mentioned in my answer (bottom line), the `ui.newContent` property is a jQuery object. You have to use `ui.newContent.attr("id")` (or `ui.newContent[0].id`).

Comment: Does anyone know why the ui.newHeader.text() contains \n even it show plain text without newline in <h3> ? how to trim that \n? I tried alert($.trim(ui.newHeader.text().replace(/\n/g, ' '))); still getting long space in between/

Comment: @Milson Newlines are usually collapsed. If you want to collapse whitespace in JavaScript as well, use `ui.newHeader.text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the active option to get info about the expanded tab:

var active = $( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active" );

I suggest you calling this in the change callback if you need to load some content on demand.